# How can I pull information from my loop and divide them seperately?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, templates

I've created a Custom Post Type that I'm trying to implement into a CSS slider. To do this I've created a custom template and added counters to get unique ID's for every new post that get's pulled.

Here's my current loop:

```
<div class="gallery autoplay items-3">  

    <?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'referanse'
    );
    $referanser = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $referanser->have_posts() ) {
        $itemcounter = 1;
        $controlcounter = 1;
        while( $referanser->have_posts() ) {
            $referanser->the_post();
            ?>

                    <div id="item-<?php echo $itemcounter++; /* echo out $itemcounter */ ?>" class="control-operator"></div>          

                    <figure class="item">
                        <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
                    </figure>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <a href="#item-<?php echo $controlcounter++; /* echo out $controlcounter */ ?>" class="control-button">•</a>
                    </div>

            <?php
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Ops, ingen referanser enda...';
    }
?>

    </div>
```

However, the markup is not as I intended, I want it to display like this:

```
<div class="gallery autoplay items-3">
    <div id="item-1" class="control-operator"></div>
    <div id="item-2" class="control-operator"></div>
    <div id="item-3" class="control-operator"></div>

    <figure class="item">
      <h1>Item 1</h1>
    </figure>

    <figure class="item">
      <h1>Item 2</h1>
    </figure>

    <figure class="item">
      <h1>Item 3</h1>
    </figure>

    <div class="controls">
      <a href="#item-1" class="control-button">•</a>
      <a href="#item-2" class="control-button">•</a>
      <a href="#item-3" class="control-button">•</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But instead, I get this:

```
<div class="gallery autoplay items-3">  
<div id="item-1" class="control-operator"></div>      
<figure class="item">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
</figure>
<div class="controls">
  <a href="#item-1" class="control-button">•</a>
</div>


<div id="item-2" class="control-operator"></div>        
<figure class="item">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
</figure>
<div class="controls">
  <a href="#item-2" class="control-button">•</a>
</div>


<div id="item-3" class="control-operator"></div>        
<figure class="item">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
</figure>
<div class="controls">
  <a href="#item-3" class="control-button">•</a>
</div>
</div>
```

So basically, what I'm asking is how can I correct the loop so it first displays the .control-operator divs, than the actual posts and lastly the control-buttons?

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put the controls in the while loop, then they will come there every time. So you can use a for loop and the `found_posts` variable to loop trough the items before and after the while loop.

Example below.

```
<div class="gallery autoplay items-3">  

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'referanse'
    );
    $referanser = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php if( $referanser->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php for($i=1; $i<=$referanser->found_posts; $i++) : ?>
            <div id="item-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="control-operator"></div>   
        <?php endfor; ?>

        <?php while( $referanser->have_posts() ) : $referanser->the_post(); ?>
            <figure class="item">
                <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
            </figure>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="controls">
        <?php for($i=1; $i<=$referanser->found_posts; $i++) : ?>
            <a href="#item-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="control-button">•</a>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>
       Ops, ingen referanser enda...
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```